# How to split path when a specific folder is met in C#

Tags: c#, string, split, directory, path

I have a path problem, let's say I have a path that look like this:

**Example 1:** `C:\AAA\BBB\FolderOfInterest\CCC\file.txt`

but it could also be like this:

**Example 2:** `C:\AAA\BBB\CCC\FolderOfInterest\DDD\EEE\file.txt`

Basically the number of directories before and after the "FolderOfInterest" is variable. I know the name of folder of interest.

I would want to split the path at the folder of interest and get only the end of it, the result of it would be :

1. `\FolderOfInterest\CCC\file.txt`
2. `\FolderOfInterest\DDD\EEE\file.txt`

I've been trying multiple kind of path splitting and recombining with string comparison to get the name of the correct folder. But it all seems messy.

Thank you

Comment: Can you garantuee that FolderOfInterest is only once in the path? For example you can't have `c:\FolderOfInterest\FolderOfInterest\FolderOfInterest` and you need the middle one?

Comment: I can technically have multiple ones, but I will always need the leftmost in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest *directory manipulation* with a help of [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-7.0) class: let check subfolder one after one until we have `folderOfInterest`. If you want the *rightmost* `folderOfInterest`:

```
c:\A\FolderOfInterest\NotfolderOfInterest\B\folderOfInterest\C\data.txt
     ^                                      ^
     leftmost                               rightmost
```

Then

```
using System.IO;

...

string path = @"C:\FolderOfInterest\DDD\EEE\file.txt";
string folderOfInterest = "FolderOfInterest";

...

// Assign the default value here (if folderOfInterest is not found)
string? result = path;

for (DirectoryInfo? di = new DirectoryInfo(path); di != null; di = di.Parent)
  if (string.Equals(di.Name, folderOfInterest, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
    result = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + 
             Path.GetRelativePath(di.Parent.FullName, path);

    break;
  }
```

For the *leftmost* just drop `break`:

```
using System.IO;

...

string path = @"C:\FolderOfInterest\DDD\EEE\file.txt";
string folderOfInterest = "FolderOfInterest";

...

// Assign the default value here (if folderOfInterest is not found)
string? result = path;

for (DirectoryInfo? di = new DirectoryInfo(path); di != null; di = di.Parent)
  if (string.Equals(di.Name, folderOfInterest, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
    result = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + 
             Path.GetRelativePath(di.Parent.FullName, path);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a robust and easy solution, you could split by the directory separator:

```
string path = @"C:\AAA\BBB\FolderOfInterest\CCC\file.txt";
string folderOfInterest = "FolderOfInterest";

var directories = path.Split('\\')
    .SkipWhile(x => x != folderOfInterest); 

var result = string.Join('\\', directories);

//If you need a initial \ add it:
//var result = @"\" + string.Join('\\', directories);
```

Note: this might use more memory and being slower than other solutions, but in most applications it should not make a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea was to use `Uri`. This will find the first occurence:

```
string GetSubdirectoryPath(string path, string dirName)
{
    if (path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));
    if (dirName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dirName));
    
    if (path.IndexOf(dirName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
        var segments = new Uri(path).Segments;
        var matchingSegments = segments
            .SkipWhile(p => !string.Equals(p, $"{dirName}/", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            .Select(p => p.Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));
        string result = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + string.Join("", matchingSegments);
        return result;
    }
    return path;
}
```

Usage:

```
string path = "C:\\AAA\\BBB\\FolderOfInterest\\CCC\\file.txt";
string dirName = "FolderOfInterest";
string result = GetSubdirectoryPath(path,dirName);
```